# NumberForm and units

Tags: programming, units

NumberForm can be used to print Quantities to a specified precision. For example,

```
x=Quantity[5.123456789,"Meters"];
5.12346 m
Print[NumberForm[x,{4,2}]]
5.12 m
```

This does exactly what I want, but it has an undesirable effect for units with exponents. For example,

```
y=Quantity[5.123456789,"Meters"/"Seconds"^2];
5.12346 m/s^2
Print[NumberForm[y,{4,2}]]
5.12 m/s^2.00
```

I'd like the precision specification to apply to the quantity, not to the units. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The problem I described in the question appears to have been resolved in Mathematica 9.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you'd like to add this definition?

```
Unprotect[NumberForm];
Format[HoldPattern@NumberForm[Quantity[n_, u_], r___]] := 
  Quantity[NumberForm[n, r], u];
Protect[NumberForm];
```

Comment: That worked for me. Thank you!!!

Comment: This is a more general problem. I face it very often when, for example, I make a fitting of some data, and then print it together with the data and the fitting function. Assume I fit a data with a function f=a*Exp[-2t^2]. What can be simpler? Assume the result of fitting is a=0.123456. Assume I want to print it with two figures after comma, i.e. like this: 0.12*Exp[-2t^2]. I do it as NumberForm[f,{3,2}] and get 0.12*Exp[-2.00*t^2], which is not what I need. However, the workaround offered by Rojo is not universal enough to be used in all such cases, say, for any fitting function possible.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, yes, it's not universal. However, it would b nice to have a clear description of the most general problem you face and how would the general solution behaviour be. Perhaps it can be done :)

Comment: [@AlexeiBoulbitch](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JOxlB.png)

Comment: Dear Rojo, I do not really know, what should I add more. The example I had in mind here is the case when I fit a list with some model function (such as f=a*Exp[-2t^2], for example typically, however, more complex), or any other, but then I want to show the plot of the list+fitting function. In this case I also place the formula of the fitting function as the epilog. Like here:Epilog -> 
 Inset[Row[{Style["f(t)="], Style[NumberForm[f, {3, 2}]]}], 
  Scaled[{0.8, 0.9}]]. This is typically done when the whole thing is subjected to manipulation and when I change the manipulation parameter

Comment: thing is subjected to manipulation and when I change the manipulation parameter the fitting is adapted and the inset part is also automatically changed, so that I see it immediately.  Another application would be an automatic generation of several such graphics.